# Abbot or Bartle for introductory/mid level in Analysis on the Real Line?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good book, aimed for self study, on beginner to intermediate level in Analysis on the Real Line, and my two principal choices are Abbot's Understanding Analysis and Bartle's Introduction to Real Analysis so, concerning these two, what would you recommend? 
I've already studied introductory real analysis in some other books, so I pretty much have some background on this matter concerning the real line basic topology, sequential and functional limits, the construction of the derivative and the Riemann-Darboux Integral, but I want to take it hard now, without skipping steps.
Any other good recommendation outside these will be gladly accepted.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then Abott's text will be pretty easy for you, why not consider baby Rudin if you want to take it hard and see full rigorous argument?